# How to obtain quantum-state purity and concurrence by measurement on quantum computer?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computer, measurement-problem

My whole question is aimed at the implementation on quantum computers utilizing quantum circuits, i.e. we can assume, that I can prepare several "copies" of the same state, without really copying it.

Ideally, I'd need to be able to evaluate both the purity
$$
P(\rho) = Tr(\rho^2)
$$

and the concurrence
$$
C(|\psi\rangle) = \sqrt{2\left(1 - Tr\left(Tr_1^2(\left |\psi\rangle \langle \psi| \right)\right)\right)},
$$

where $Tr_1$ represents a partial trace of the input state, i.e. we're obtaining a reduced density matrix.

As I'm working with [Qiskit toolbox](https://qiskit.org/), I know, that we can obtain all the above-mentioned quantities in the statevector simulation like this:

- https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.purity.html
- https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.concurrence.html
- https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.partial_trace.html#qiskit.quantum_info.partial_trace

Also, outside of statevector simulation regime I can utilize [Quantum State Tomography](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stable/0.24/tutorials/noise/8_tomography.html). The problems are that a) it's quite cumbersome and presenting a huge overhead in our runtime and b) it's NOT compatible with current [Session](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/lab/docs/iql/manage/systems/sessions/)-based approach in Qiskit.

**So, my question is, am I able to obtain both the purity and the concurrence of my state directly by (repeated) measurements? To be clear, I'm trying to implement an algorithm, where both quantities are used in a cost function, so I need their floating-point values, not only boolean flag, etc.**

I found some information in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/212486/115566), but obtaining of the purity value seems somewhat unclear to me and the concurrence is not mentioned at all.

Comment: it's not clear whether you're specifically asking about ways that don't involve state tomography. If so, what exactly are the resources allowed? You say repeated measurements, but what kinds of measurements (in what bases, etc)? You can estimate any function of $\rho$, as long as your measurement is complete (albeit your estimate might possibly be quite bad if the statistics is not sufficient)

Comment: @glS I'll improve my question... Yes, I'm asking about the ways, which do not include state tomography, as I'm using it right now and it introduces a huge runtime overhead into my solver... By repeated measurements I meant measurements in computational basis to mitigate the sampling noise.